# C# equivalent of this stream related code (Java)

Tags: java, c#, networking, stream

I'm more of a Java developer than a C# developer, but I work with both languages; Unfortunately I'm nowhere near the level of most people in either language, but that's why I'm constantly asking questions and reading to expand my knowledge.

Currently I've been working on a Server/Client in Java which works wonderfully, I've written a test client in Java for a game that I've been working on in Unity3D. Honestly, I would just use Java for the entire game if the community was there to easily get level designers etc.

In this code, I'm using a  [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) in java, and the setup looks like this:

```
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Throughout this code, I perform the following logic to check to make sure all of the data for a specified packet as arrived:

```
if(dataIn.available() < 4) {
    continue;
}

dataIn.mark(4);
int length = dataIn.readInt();
System.out.println("Packet length is" + length);

if(dataIn.available() < length) {
    System.out.println("Only read " + dataIn.available() + "/ " + length + " bytes.");
    dataIn.reset();
    continue;
}
```

and I've been struggling to find an equivalent to this in C#. -- Other issues I've noticed is that a byte being sent by java's DataOutputStream, and the byte being read by C#'s BinaryReader is not always the same, but that's another problem.

Comment: Streams are fairly straightforward in c#.  What specific feature are you looking for? Buffering?

Comment: I would assume so; I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to the technical names for functionality. Basically, I need to be able to read from the data, and store it into a `buffer?` of sorts. Once the `buffer?` is 4 bytes long, I will read an integer from it. This integer holds the `length` of the incoming packet, and will not continue to read any data from the buffer until all of the bytes are available. (if the length is 32, then 32bytes are required in the `buffer?` before we read any data)

Comment: Basically, it's an implementation to prevent TCP Segmentation that I've used on my Java servers/clients for the last few years, and I'm having some trouble finding the right classes/methods to use in C#. -- what the `#mark(int)` feature does is tells the `buffer?`~ this is the current spot we should read from is, then the `#reset()` method will say our position to read from goes back to what it was before we started reading. (IE, we started from 4bytes in, there wasn't enough data, start at 4bytes in next time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this reads all the expected data in a memorystream. Further processing of the received data is possible by using the memorystream as a stream, or by getting the bytes in it with memoryStream.ToArray().

```
        using (var ns = new NetworkStream(socket))
        {
            int dataLength = 0;

            // reading the datalength
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                while (!ns.DataAvailable)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                }

                dataLength = (dataLength << 8) + ns.ReadByte();
            }

            // reading the data
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (memoryStream.Length < dataLength)
                {
                    while (!ns.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                    }

                    bytesRead = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: minimalistic approach
Beware of the socket.ReceiveBufferSize when using this approach! If it's smaller than data size you're in for a long sleep.

```
        Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();

        while (socket.Available < 4)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        }

        byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[4];
        socket.Receive(lengthBuffer);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(lengthBuffer);
        int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

        while (socket.Available < dataLength)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        }

        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataLength];
        socket.Receive(dataBuffer);
```

Comment: Could you please explain this line to me: `dataLength = (dataLength << 4) + ns.ReadByte();` - At this point, You'd be doing dataLength = (0 << 4) + #; What's purpose does the bitshift to the left serve? Integers come in as 4 bytes, bitshifed by 4 different values (Atleast in my networking, I send everything as an uint, then convert on the client side. This is showing a base example of reading all of the data, but would reading seperate data still move along the stream? (Ex, if I sent a long then an int, could I read the long, then the int without any problems? not at my home to check)

Comment: The idea was that the first 4 bytes would be an int32. My guess was that java would send the high bits first (it's a guess!). So i read the four bytes, bit-shifting the already received bytes to the left to reconstruct the int32. Every byte you read, 'moves along' the stream.

Comment: OH, I see! So, it's basically the same as the following code, just done in a loop instead: http://pastebin.com/QntPZZwa -- This is a `c#` conversion of have java reads ints that I wrote. Here's how Java reads integers, (You're correct, it's an int32). http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataInputStream.java#DataInputStream.readInt%28%29 -- But shouldn't the code be bitshifitng 8 bits, not 4?

Comment: It's the same as your code. Snag, you're right about the 8 bit shift! I'll change it in my answer.

Comment: Marked as correct, however is there a method to find the "estimated" or "total" bytes available? Here you're using `while (!ns.DataAvailable)` however in my example (java) I'm calling `dataIn.available()` which returns an integer containing the amount of bytes available to be read from. How would I go about this? (This would be used for flushing out data, say I recieve 60bytes, read 42, and need to calculate the remaining bytes in the buffer (which would be 18) and read them to remove them from the stack.  (Such as a read(remainingbytes) type of thing. The reason this is confusing me is becaus

Comment: e you offered a solution to this using the `MemoryStream` but I don't understand how the MemoryStream is being constructed to use the ns. It probably has something to do with the using() block, wouldn't it normally be a constructor parameter? I'm working on an API, so I need to have things as seperated as possible. and nesting this could cause a mess.

Comment: The `socket.Available` property show you the available bytes at the moment http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx The memorystream gets filled with the write command. If you want to use the memory stream further in the code, you need to remove the using surrounding it and just create it.

Comment: Thank you for everything! I'll make another attempt at this when I get home and see what happens; Would you mind if I messaged you if I have any problems with the code related above?

Comment: I added another 'minimalistic' example. (Your question about the available bytes gave me the idea :-))

Comment: Thanks, I'll be opening another question momentarily about consistency issues between Java<->C# (Values aren't being read as they're sent)